# Batch zipping multiple files into a single archive

Tags: windows, batch, zip

I have the following drag-and-drop batch script for creating zip files

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto :eof
:loop
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%~1.zip" "%~1"
shift
if not [%1]==[] goto loop
```

This creates separate files for a bunch of directories dragged onto the batch. I now want to do the same, but create a **single archive** at the end. How do I do that?

Comment: I thought 7zip could integrate itself into the file manager, so you can just right-click and choose some actions like "add to archive"...

Comment: you can, but I want to do it through a batch file. I want to drag nwjs app files onto a batch to create .nw zipped packages

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `7z.exe` (or `7za.exe` allegedly) is a command line version of `7-zip`, an executable program used to compress, extract and update files through the command line, and suppose the same usage:

```
7za.exe
Usage: 7za <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...] [<@listfiles...>]
```

Then next script could work with `%*`. In a batch script,  `%*` refers to all the [arguments](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) (as many as 255)

```
@echo off
set "archivename=any_name_of_your_choice"

rem insert here some code to figure out a value for %archivename% variable

set /p "archivename=archive name, Enter for default %archivename%: "

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%archivename%.zip" %*
```